# Launch Microsoft document explorer

Tags: visual-studio

In visual studio editor, when F1 is pressed Microsoft document explorer launches with MSDN

In my machine i have installed both VS2005 and VS2008.Also MSDn for VS2008.

Is it possible to launch MSDN 2008 help from VS2005

Currently i explicitly open MSDN libary for 2008 and search. I feel that is pain ful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try a VS2005 help URL<sup>1</sup> in the VS2008 help. If it works then you could add a favourite to the VS2008 help. Otherwise I suspect you are out of luck.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Something like: `ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/dv_vstoc/html/06ddebea-2c83-4a45-bb48-6264c797ed93.htm`

<sup>2</sup> I expect this to be the case, help formats are often updated/expanded with help viewer revisions that go with VS releases.